# How to make Excel pay attention to the clipboard

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, copy-paste, clipboard

I use Excel 2013 for a few hours every day, and I really hate it. Outlook is worse, but most of the Office suite saps productivity rather than increasing it.

One example, which maybe someone can help me with, is this:
I copy a record ID from Excel and paste it into a SQL query, which gives me a bunch of rows related to the record. Then I copy the rows and want to paste it into Excel and manipulate the data. When I press paste I get the single cell ID from Excel pasted in, rather than the data I've just copied to the clipboard. I then have to press ESC in Excel, then copy and paste in the data again. Why doesn't Excel just paste what I've copied to the clipboard?

All the workarounds we have to come up with Microsoft's idiosyncrasies results in great websites like superuser.com, but also lot of wasted time.

Comment: This probably isn't Excel's fault.  What application are you using for running the SQL queries?

Comment: Hi @misha256, I'm using SQLyog, but it is unrelated. Try this, type two lines into Notepad, open Excel and type something into a cell, copy the cell value in Excel and paste it in Notepad, then copy the lines in Notepad and paste it into Excel. In Excel you'll get a copy of the cell you previously copied, not the text from Notepad. To get the data from Notepad you then have to press ESC in Excel, go back to Notepad and copy the data again, then go back to Excel and paste.

Comment: When you Paste the first time around, are you using the CTRL-V shortcut, or just pressing ENTER? CTRL-V should work first go.

Comment: IMHO, your understanding of the functioning of clipboard is incorrect. It does not work the way you cited in your comment

Comment: Hi @Prasanna, can you explain how the clipboard should work, then? I thought the last thing copied should be the item pasted. I've been using Windows since Version 2 and Excel is the only program not to work like this.

Comment: Hi @misha256, I'm pressing CTRL-V, or SHIFT-INSERT

Comment: Hi @Prasanna,  I know why it is, it is because Excel doesn't use the clipboard. Excel manages it's 'copy' and 'move' functions itself, without any reference to the clipboard, so that it can manage cell references, etc. This is why my question is 'How to make Excel pay attention to the clipboard' as I don't want Excel to work the way it has been programmed to. I want to unbind myself from Microsoft inefficiencies.

Comment: @ThesleWilliams Wait a second... could it be this? I think so! http://www.technipages.com/office-turn-office-clipboard-on-off. I *always* turn Office Clipboard off which is why I can't seen to replicate your issue. Worth a shot :-)

Comment: Hi @misha256, THAT'S IT. Thankyou. I showed the Office clipboard and suddenly Office was now finding items that I copy to the clipboard in other apps as well. Now I can copy and paste again. Copy and Paste your comment into an Answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is caused by [Office Clipboard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-and-paste-multiple-items-by-using-the-Office-Clipboard-714a72af-1ad4-450f-8708-c2931e73ec8a). When enabled (which it is by default), it modifies the usual system-wide copy/paste functions so that you can copy/paste multiple items between Office documents.

The solution to your issue is to disable Office Clipbaord:

1. Select *Home*
2. Select the arrow next to *Clipboard*
3. Select *Options* at the bottom-left of the window
4. Un-check all options

[image: Disable Office Clipboard]

Feel free to play around with these options, some might prove useful after all!

Credit for these instructions goes entirely to: http://www.technipages.com/office-turn-office-clipboard-on-off

Comment: This does not turn off Office's internal clipboard; it simply stops the sidebar from displaying. Office (specifically Excel) will continue to override the system clipboard internally, which is hugely frustrating for people moving things between Excel and other programs.

Answer (score -3):

Check out the `Edit->Paste Special` feature.  It gives you options for pasting, including pasting just values (or just formats, or formulae, etc.) I use it frequently when I want values instead of references to be pasted.

Comment: Hi Greg, this still just pastes in the value from the highlighted cell in Excel, it doesn't paste in the values I've just copied to the clipboard.

Comment: That is odd.  I have sometimes seen behavior like this when cutting/pasting between windows/applications on different machines, but usually if you can cut/paste in one direction, you can do it in the other.  Can you verify that the text is in your cut buffer by pasting it into a text file?

Comment: Hi @Greg, if I paste it into another application it will paste in the data I have copied elsewhere. It is only Excel, which appears to override the Windows clipboard with the data in the cell that was previously copied in Excel. Pressing ESC in Excel clears the call selection, but also clears the clipboard, so you have to go into the other application and copy it again. See my comments to misha256 above.